# Unexpected Type Mismatch While Using Scala breeze.optimize.linear.LinearProgram

Tags: scala, linear-programming, scala-breeze

Right now I am playing around with the Linear Program class in Scala Breeze and I've gotten up to the point where I am going to optimize my linear programming problem using the following code.

```
import breeze.stats.distributions
import breeze.stats._
import breeze.linalg._

val lp = new breeze.optimize.linear.LinearProgram()
val unif_dist = breeze.stats.distributions.Uniform(-1,1)

val U = DenseMatrix.rand(1, 3, unif_dist).toArray
val V = DenseMatrix.rand(2, 3, unif_dist).toArray.grouped(3).toArray
val B = Array.fill(3)(lp.Binary())

val Objective = V.map(vi => U.zip(vi).map(uv => uv._1 * uv._2)).map(uvi => B.zip(uvi).map(buv => buv._1 * buv._2)).map(x => x.reduce(_ + _)).reduce(_ + _)
val lpp = ( Objective subjectTo() )

lp.maximize(lpp)
```

I receive the following error

```
scala> lp.minimize(lpp)
<console>:45: error: type mismatch;
found   : lp.Problem
required: lp.Problem
          lp.minimize(lpp)
                      ^
```

Has anyone here run into this before, and if so, did you come up with a way to fix it? Additionally, I am open to suggestions on a cleaner way to write the line where I asssign Objective.

Comment: compiles for me. (throws because it's unbounded, of course).

Comment: also, sorry, there's not a better way to do the multiply right now. I kind of stopped working on the LP API. (I have aspirations of finishing it, but I have more aspirations than I have time.)

Comment: Thank you for the response. What versions of breeze and scala are you using?

Comment: 2.11.7, 0.12-SNAPSHOT